# Javascript not loading when page loaded from index link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a form that has a good deal of Javascript (jquery specifically).  When I navigate to the page by entering its url manually, or when I'm redirected to it from my login page, all the javascript elements load just fine.  However when I navigate to the page from a link in the index, none of the javascript loads unless I refresh.  (I don't know if this is a problem exclusive to index; index simply happens to contain the only link to the form).

I've consolidated all my JavaScript to `init.js` which I've `require`d in my `application.js`.  It is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// scolling accelleration
  $(".anchor_link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top } , 1000);
  } );
  $('#save').click(function(){
    $('#save_alert').animate({"bottom":"100px"}, "slow").delay(800).animate({"bottom":"50px"}, "slow");
  });
//styling radio buttons  
  function radStyle(entity){
    $(entity).find('input[type="radio"]').css("display", "none");
    $(entity).find('input[type="radio"]').parent().prepend('<span class="radiospan fa-stack">')
    $(entity).find("span.radiospan").append('<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-inverse">')
    $(entity).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').siblings("span.radiospan").append('<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x">');
  }
//calling radio buttons on document ready
  radStyle(document);
//adding interactive radio button functionality (delegate to provide functionality to dynamically generated fields)
  $('div.form-right').delegate('input[type="radio"]', 'click', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).siblings("span.radiospan").append('<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x">');
      $(this).closest('span.radio').siblings('span.radio').find('i.fa.fa-circle.fa-stack-1x').remove();
    }
  });
//select menus on initial load
  $('select').customSelect();
//styling select menus and radio buttons upon dynamic content generation
  var nests = [ "dynamic-officer", "dynamic-director", "dynamic-contractor-person", "dynamic-contractor-org", "dynamic-ip", "dynamic-shareholder"];
  nests.forEach(function(nest){
    $("#"+nest).on("cocoon:after-insert", function(e, added_item){
      added_item.find('select').customSelect();
      radStyle(added_item);
    });
  });
} );
```

**A few more notes**

- Adding to my confusion, firebug seems to acknowledge the existence of my init.js and doesn't throw anything in the errors console.
- I have noticed that if I copy everything in my `init.js` into an embedded `<script>` section in my view, it loads just fine.

Anyway, it's entirely possible that this is just how rails works and I need to use script tags in my view (I thought I'd read that it wasn't but who knows).  Any pointers on this matter would certainly be appreciated; thanks in advance to anyone who sets me straight on this.

In case it has anything to do with the error, my `index.html.erb` is

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Incorporation#index</h1>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <% @incorporations.each do |incorporation| %>
      <tr>
    <td class="name">
      <% begin %>
        <%= link_to incorporation.company.names.first.name_string, edit_incorporation_path(incorporation) %>
      <% rescue %>
        <%= link_to "Untitled Company", edit_incorporation_path(incorporation) %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td class="email"><%= link_to incorporation.user.email, incorporation %></td>
    <td class="created_at"><%= link_to incorporation.created_at, edit_incorporation_path(incorporation) %></td>
    <td class="generate"><%= button_to "Generate Documents", incorpgenerate_incorporation_path(incorporation), :remote => true, :method => :post %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an issue related to the [Turbolink](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/) gem. This gem comes with Rails 4 by default and has been known to cause a ton of issues with javascript calls such as '(document).ready(function($)'. The reason for this is that the Turbolink gem avoids fully loading all of your applications assets(JS and CSS) while navigating between pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think is turbolinks.

Read this: 
[Jquery Turbolinks Gem](http://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)